# Customizing Caption Formats for Figures and Tables in Numbered and Unnumbered Chapters in LaTeX

Tags: tables, floats, chapters

I'm currently working on a LaTeX document (documentclass{svmono) where I have both numbered and unnumbered chapters. In my document, I'm using figures and tables, and I've noticed that the captions for these figures and tables in unnumbered chapters have an extra space and a dot between the figure or table number and the text caption. This formatting is not consistent with what I desire, and I would like to get rid of the "space" and "dot" in these captions.

I've tried various approaches, including using the caption package to redefine the caption formats for figures and tables. However, despite my efforts, I haven't been able to achieve the desired result.

For example, in my unnumbered chapters, I want the captions for figures and tables to appear as follows:

```
Figure 1: Caption text without the extra space and dot.
Table 1: Caption text without the extra space and dot.
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to customize the caption formats for figures and tables specifically within unnumbered chapters to remove the extra space and dot.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{svmono} % or another class

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

% Define a new caption label format called "plain" for figures
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{plain}{\figurename~#2}

% Set up caption format for figures to use the "plain" label format
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=plain}

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Numbered Chapter}
    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Figure in numbered chapter}
    \end{figure}
    
    \chapter*{Unnumbered Chapter}
    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Figure in unnumbered chapter}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: If you use 'another class', the problem doesn't exist. (Try `book`, for instance.) So we can't use your MWE to reproduce the problem because we don't have `svmono.cls`. (At least, I don't and I've got TeX Live installed. And it doesn't seem to be on CTAN.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot
I got the problem resolved using
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}